# javascript-show works, but not hide

Tags: javascript, css, hide, element

hi I'm running a fairly simple script which shows the content in the hidden div when clicked. the problem is the "hide" element does not work only" show".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".hide, .show").show().on('click', function(e) {
        var elm = $(e.target).is('.show') ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).parent().prev('.show');
        elm.toggle().next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle()
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
.slidingDiv {
    display: none;
    height:200px;
    width:auto;
}
</style

<div id="footer-widgets-container">
    <div id="footer-widgets" class="col-full col-4"> <a href="#" class="show">Show</a>

        <div class="slidingDiv">
            <div class="block footer-widget-1 widget">
                <div class="col1a"></div>
                <div class="col3c"></div>
                <div class="col2b"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block footer-widget-2"></div>
            <div class="block footer-widget-3"></div>
            <div class="block footer-widget-4">
                <div class="skype p"><a href="#"><p>Skype</p></a>
                </div>
                <div class="email p"><a href="#"><p>Email</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>

</div>
```

Comment: The hide doesn't work? As in the function hide or the div with the class hide?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nG8Sm/1/. Use it to describe what you want.

Comment: The div class utilizing "hide" does hide the footer whereas "show" shows the footer I just can't hide it once its shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use the wrong selector.

You could either change your `hide` tag so it is inside the correct `div` or change your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".hide, .show").show().on('click', function(e) {
            var elm = $(e.target).is('.show') ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).parent().find('.show');
            elm.toggle().next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle()
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have changed `$(e.target).parent().prev('. show')` to `$(e.target).parent().find('.show')` because `show` is not inside that `div`.

Hope it helps.